# How to select a button without validating form

Tags: html, required

How do I prevent the form from checking the required field when I select the "Average Household Income" button.

```
<form method="post">  The 
<input type="text" name="myIncome[0][Income]" required
  placeholder="#######.##" pattern="^(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{2}$)?" />

<input type="submit" name='cmdSubmit' value="Submit" 
formaction="ProjectCensus.php">

<input type="submit" name='cmdAvgHousehold' value="Average Household Income" 
formaction="Average_household.php">
```

Comment: Don't make it a type=submit. Add a click event handler and use javascript to send the URL to the server

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a `type='submit'` for the actual submit button, but for the other buttons (the ones that do not submit) they should be HTML `<button>`'s. I am assuming the OP chose `type='submit'` to get the visual appearance of a HTML `<button>` for the other inputs *(see answer below)*

Answer (score 0):

You would want to change the type on that button.

Try:

```
<button type="button" ... ></button>
```

*Updated as per request*: 
I recommend you use JQuery `ajax()` for handling the submitting of the form (it will be the easiest to understand).

```js
$("#myForm").submit(ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "Average_household.php",
    // data: {},
    success: resp => {
      alert("Submitted comment");
    },
    error: resp => {
      alert("There was an error submitting this form");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- src: https://html.com/attributes/button-type/ -->
<form id="myForm" action="/button-type">

  <button type="button" onclick="alert('This button does nothing.')">Click me for no reason!</button>

  <br><br>
  <label for="name">Name</label><br>
  <input name="name"><br><br> <button type="reset">Reset the form!</button><br><br>

  <button type="submit" disabled>Submit (disabled)</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: When I click on the "button", I want to execute the php code in file "Average_household.php".  The onclick is only for JavaScript.  Is there a way to only execute the JavaScipt code to validate the form only when the Submit button is selected?

Comment: @sra2786, yes there is a way to do this without submitting the form, you want to do use `ajax`, I will update my question